# Scrape a data links of a page with JavaScript from R

Tags: javascript, html, r, web-scraping

*Please help me.*

I am new to web scraping in R. I want to collect the link
download data tables on this page (http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/). My project is to make these data more accessible.

Here is the website : http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/

In the page *Donnée* I have a list of the sectors.
Agriculture: 43 tables
Public Help: 7 tables
...

When I click on *Agriculture* I get the dataset list.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cInWz62HjbcpgJ00rK-8Q-0p71mC59hq

1. I want to get the list of these titles.
2. For each title get the download link of the dataset.

I tried this code below to see the structure of the site.
But I do not see the architecture that can allow me to extract these links.

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(rvest)
URL <- "http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/"
pg <- read_html(URL)
p <- html_children(pg)[1]
pp <- html_children(pg)[2]
html_structure(p)
html_structure(pp)
```

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(rvest)
URL <- "http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/data/#topic=Agriculture"
pg <- read_html(URL)
p <- html_children(pg)[1]
pp <- html_children(pg)[2]
html_structure(p)
html_structure(pp)
```

For example, I tried this code for links in  tags.
But I do not get the differents download links.

```
URL <- "http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/data/#topic=Agriculture"
pg <- read_html(URL)
all.url <- html_attr(html_nodes(pg, "a"), "href")
all.url <- as.data.frame(all.url)
```

As results I expect, For each itm the
list of tables and download links. For example:

for Public Aid (7):

label links

Aide extérieure par secteur de 1995 à 2006 (en millions de FCFA) download links
Aide extérieure par type (en millions de FCFA)                      download links

*Please help me.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Web traffic and API call:**

So, if you start ,for example, with

`http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/data/#menu=topic`

You can see the list of all the top level links along with the counts of their datasets. If we were to click on `Aide Publique (7)` we would then see the 7 sections which, if you click on any, then present you with `Select dataset`.

If you monitor the web-traffic when doing that first click you will see the API POST request made to retrieve the data for `Aide Publique (7)`:

[image]

If we further inspect the request we can observe the query string params in the url and the request payload:

[image]

The params is basically some info about us we can probably remove; and a little experimentation with the payload shows, if we exclude the payload, we actually get all the topics and not just `Aide Publique (7)`.

---

**The API response:**

Now, the response is json and is an array but in R that means a list. Looking at part of one item in the list as an example:

[image]

A comparison of that info versus the actual dataset links e.g.

[image]

Clicking on the `Select DataSet` yields the end url of

`http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/nthpfqd/aide-ext%C3%A9rieure-par-secteur-de-1995-%C3%A0-2006-en-millions-de-fcfa`

A quick comparison with list item 1 (prior image of json) shows that this if we consider this new url decoded:

`http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/nthpfqd/aide-extérieure-par-secteur-de-1995-à-2006-en-millions-de-fcfa`

is of the format:

`'http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/{item["id"]}/{item["title"]}'`

meaning, in a loop over the json response object we can generate the final links by concatenating a base string with the current item `id` and current item `title`. We can also extract the title from the current item `name`. We can use `purrr` and `map_df` to handle the loop and final dataframe generation and `httr` to make the POST.

---

**R:**

```
library(httr)
library(purrr)

r <- content(POST("http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/api/1.0/meta/dataset"))

df <- map_df(r, function(item) {

  data.frame(title = item$name,
             url = paste0("http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/", item$id,'/',item$title),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})

View(df)
```

---

**Py:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.post('http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/api/1.0/meta/dataset').json()
df = pd.DataFrame([(item['name'], f'http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/{item["id"]}/{item["title"]}') for item in r]
                  ,columns = ['Title','Url'])
print(df)
```

Comment: **Thank you very much for your quick response @QHarr. It helps me a lot already. And that answers my question**. 

Now how can I download my data. I did a function to download the first link. But he sends me the code html (xml).

Here is the first link that your script retrieves :

`link <- 'http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/ajcalpd/accidents-de-la-circulation-constatés-par-la-gendarmerie-nationale'`

Comment: I made this code to download it :

`downloadImages <- function(files, name, outPath){
  for(i in 1:length(files)){
    download.file(files, destfile = paste0(outPath, "/", name, "_", i, ".csv"), mode = 'wb')
  }
  
}
outPath="E:/opendata"
name="data"
downloadImages(link,name, outPath)`

Comment: The links I am extracting I don't think initiates a download. I don't see anything that would. Can you tell me for 'http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/ajcalpd/accidents-de-la-circulation-constatés-par-la-gendarmerie-nationale'  what the download link is you were expecting?

Comment: I want the download link of this dataset : https://drive.google.com/open?id=10dD8RCHQjR6gBPZeCsktPb3vr-DL1V2-

when you follow the link, on the right you have a button that allows you to download the table : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gvg2O49Dv0qYLvHF6a0OOz4THdVfK2HD

Comment: For this page http://burkinafaso.opendataforafrica.org/ajcalpd/accidents-de-la-circulation-constat%C3%A9s-par-la-gendarmerie-nationale this is what I see: https://tmpfiles.org/download/26709/Untitled.png

Comment: Basically a pretty blank page.

Comment: When you arrive on the page. You like that result : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bnP1sTyOOAWzQ3aK3ZgIsPhU1F03f5Mo 


And when you make a selection in the menu on the right, the data table is displayed. for example :https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ffUfEVkIawmLiLRJariBP_DNCoyuHr9q

Comment: I inspect the html code of the download button : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pIZjY62rNkZOJE9rzKQHxOrQaFWFNvam

Comment: I see. It doesn't render properly in my chrome browser version but does in MS Edge. You have to have a registered account in order to perform downloads (view the download process). This will be a new and involved question I think as it likely involves monitoring the web traffic when performing a download to see what actually is happening. I think there is a POST  request made but it may require some form of authentication (possibly from stored cookies passed post login).